# Delphi Spring4D Adapters units

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I just installed Spring4D to test, but it cannot find the `Spring.Persistence.Adapters` units. I tried to install of multiple ways, put all the folders manually in my IDE library, but still cannot find any adapter. If I add a adapter unit manually, it returns a `{$I Spring.inc}` error.

Not found any help about this specific error, and Spring Google group was banned.

Has anyone had this problem and managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

These units are located in the `Source\Persistence\Adapters` folder.

They are not precompiled via the runtime packages because each of them is for specific data access component libraries (ADO, FireDAC, etc) and thus would require all of them when compiling the `Spring.Persistence` package which would cause failure for like everyone.

This means you have following possibilities:

- explicitly add the adapters unit for the data access component of your choice to the project
- add the aforementioned folder to

  - the search path of your project where you want to use them
  - the library path of your IDE

All of these also require adding the `Source` directory to either the search path of the project or the library path of your IDE because that is the folder where `Spring.inc` is located.